# Visual Studio 2010 'Assign to local variable' function?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm in love with the function in Eclipse "assign to field". Basically, when I have

```
getString();
```

and I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>, Eclipse converts this into

```
String getString = getString();
```

Is this possible in VS 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the thing you're looking for is a refactoring typically called "introduce variable". As far as I know, Visual Studio doesn't support this. However [ReSharper](http://jetbrains.com/resharper/) and other tools like it do.

Comment: Thanks, do you know of a free alternative?

Comment: [CodeRush Xpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/) seems to support it.

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked in eclipse for years so I am not familiar with the example, but have you tried code snippets in VS?

There is a tool for customizing them that you can get from [here](http://snippeteditor.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Resharper Shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>V</kbd>