# Using quick shortcut for C# to place variable

Tags: c#, java, visual-studio-2012

In eclipse there is a shortcut ctrl+1:

When you write a method, it automatically gives you the place parameter.

For example if I write `get.name();`

and press ctrl+1 it automatically puts for me `String name = get.name();`

assuming the method output is string.

Is there something similar in C# ?,I have tried with CTRL+. without success...

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you'll get is the [introduce variable](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Introduce_Variable.html) with ReSharper.

This will introduce a variable for the selected expression.

There is nothing built into Visual Studio, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

See this [Msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lisa/archive/2010/07/25/vs-2010-keyboard-shortcuts-for-c-vb-c-f-now-available-in-letter-8-5x11in-and-a4-210-215-297mm-print-ready-sizes.aspx)  site, Here are lot of short keys for c# ,and if you switch to [the Visual C# keyboard mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366739%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) scheme, then can access more key's

> But I know c# have not call the method when click ctr1\

And some other details , you can see this previous discussion : [Visual Studio 2010 'Assign to local variable' function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793581/visual-studio-2010-assign-to-local-variable-function)